# MVC Razor routing suggestion

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, url-routing

I have a web site with something like this:
http://website/Controller/Action/Id

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Controller", action = "Action", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

Is there any way to route to the same action if the url changes to be
http://website/Action/Id

I was trying to change global.asax but nothing is working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on how I'm reading your question, you're saying that you may only ever have one controller and want to be able to route all actions to that single controller?

If I'm reading it correctly, you should be able to do something similar to this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Controller", action = "Action", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```